# Excel, how to count multiple records of words

Tags: excel, sorting, conditional-statements

So I have a table sorta looking like this

```
f1  f2
EF  German
EF  German
EF  America
RF  Britain
RF  Britain
DF  German
DF  America
DF  Britain
```

ok so how do I create another field, which combines the other fields and counts everything on field 2?
so it would end up like this

```
f1  f2     calculated field
EF  German  2
EF  America 1
RF  Britain 2
DF  German  1
DF  America 1
DF  Britain 1
```

I am very confused on how to do this on Microsoft Excel, if you would help me thank you.

Comment: Pivot table or SUMIFS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you could use:

**Formula:**

`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,A2,$B$2:$B$9,B2)`

**Image:**

[image]

After you get the values you could go and remove duplicates:

- Data tab
- Data Tools
- Remove Duplicates